# How to add PHP ssl extension on an existing installation?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. Surprisingly i didn't find any previous question that deals with this.

Anyway, my goal is to add the openssl extension to my existing Linux server

I didn't find that this extension is available when running:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/pecl list-all | grep ssl
```

A few other details:

```
OS Type: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.2 (Maipo)
Full spec: Linux 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 29 17:29:29 EDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
PHP Version: PHP 7.0.10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check what modules are installed already by the system with `php -m`, you will find that the `openssl` module is already installed. It's part of the PHP core and therefore not available as an optional module via `pecl`.

Comment: If so why in my windows installation i have the following line enabled : "extension=php_openssl.dll" , shouldn't there be the equivalent in my linux server?